# HttpRequest (variable request might not have been initialized) in jsp

Tags: jsp

```
<% 
    String action=request.getParameter("search");
    if("keysearch".equals(action))
                   {
        String key=request.getParameter("keyword");
        search(key);
    }
    else if("Reserve".equals(action))
    {
        String selected=request.getParameter("select");
        System.out.println(selected);
        reserve(selected);
    }                   
%>
```

i tried this code but it gives error like variable request might not have been initialized
---- please help me out

Comment: Please give **exact** error text.

Comment: Should be using out.Write not System.Out it will not write to the DOM.
The If should be (action.equals("keysearch")) <- That is what you are asking you just have it in reverse.
search and reserve are method in the pages some where? 
T

Comment: actually i have 2 buttons in my applications like reserve and search , how can i create 2 functions in one .jsp form